# Error when importing WindowProporties in Python

Tags: python, import, panda3d

I installed Panda3D with this command:

```
pip3 install panda3d==1.10.6
```

Then I made **main**.py:

```
from direct.showbase.ShowBase import ShowBase
from panda3d.core import WindowProporties

class Game(ShowBase):
    def __init__(self):
        ShowBase.__init__(self)     

        self.Proporties = WindowProporties
        self.Proporties.setSize(500, 500)
        self.win.requestProperties(properties)

if __name__ == "__main__": Game = Game()
```

When I run this code it give error:

```
python3 __main__.py
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from panda3d.core import WindowProporties
ImportError: cannot import name 'WindowProporties' from 'panda3d.core' (/home/kali/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/panda3d/core.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I am using:

- Kali Linux Live
- Python 3.8.2

Thanks to everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have a typo in your import, try this:

```
from panda3d.core import WindowProperties
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is my bad English :)